# JSF 1.2 selectManyCheckbox : throwing exception as is not of type Array or List

Tags: jsf-1.2

I am using JSF1.2 & myfaces implementation. 
The correnponding jars used are jsf-api-1.2_04-p02.jar & myfaces-impl-1.2.9.jar.

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{restrictionMaintBean.selectedRestrictionTypeList}" layout="pageDirection" tabindex="5" onchange="setChangeFlag(true);">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{restrictionMaintBean.restrictionTypeList}"/>
                                </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

This code runs fine on tomcat 6.0.20 but tomcat 6.0.35 it gives below exception:

> org.apache.myfaces.component.html.ext.HtmlPanelGrid,Id: a18][Class:
>   javax.faces.component.html.HtmlSelectManyCheckbox,Id:
>   j_id_jsp_1445681841_62]} is not of type Array or List
>           at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.internalSubmittedOrSelectedValuesAsSet(RendererUtils.java:716)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getSelectedValuesAsSet(RendererUtils.java:615)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.renderCheckboxList(HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.java:112)
>           at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlCheckboxRendererBase.java:65)